# Magento 1.9.2 Configurable product- single product order has 2 items with price zero

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, magento-1.9.2.0, associate-products

I'm following configurable product structure in my magento store. If i order and item it shown normally on magento panel. But when accessing through SOAP or 3rd party plugins it has duplicate order with price zero.

Example:

[image]

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

in Magento configurable product you have two items in quote .

One is main configurable product and the secound one is associate simple product as per your selection .

You get price for main product and also you get change price if you have applied and change price for that option then you will get that change price

i.e : if on size selection If I increase `100$` then with 2nd product I will get `100`

Hope you will understand why you get 2 product in your case